# Ferramentas de armazenamento/indexação de logs

Tags: log, big-data

Preciso criar um sistema para armazenar *logs* de diversas ações dos usuários (este sistema criará milhões de dados semanais).

Então quais as ferramentas disponíveis para este tipo de necessidade?

PS.: É extremamente necessário a disponibilização de uma API para pesquisa dos logs, pois os mesmos serão apresentados em uma tela do sistema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem alguns sistemas de armazenamento e gerenciamento centralizado de logs.
Duas sugestões que eu posso te indicar são o [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) e o [Elastic Stack](https://www.elastic.co/products).

Basta redirecionar seus logs para uma dessas duas aplicações, criar seus filtros, gerar seus gráficos estatísticos e alertas.
Já usei essas duas ferramentas para fazer análise de trafego de redes e logs de firewall.

Comment: Valeu Anderson, o Elastic eu já estava vendo, mas não conhecia esse Graylog, vou dar uma olhada nas _features_ dele.